# Changing background color of each cell dynamically depending on its value

Tags: css, perl, html-table, html-email

I have table with two columns loading from oracle database.

one column contains `employee_name` and another column is `phone_no`

I am running the `css` script in perl to send an `html` table in email. However I want to represent the table in a user friendly manner.

**e.g.:**

1. I want to change the bg colour to red for column 1 cell where `emplpyee_name=steven`.
2. I want to change the bg colour to red for column 2 cells where `phone_no=null`

I want to change the `bgcolour` during the load dynamically. I don't want `jQuery`, only in css/html it is possible?

```
#!/efs/dist/perl5/core/5.8/exec/bin/perl

use EFSPerl::Version (
'DBD-Oracle' => '1.19',
'DBI' => '1.58'
);


use DBI;
use CommonFunctions;

my @HTML        =();


$STYLE=<<STYLE;
<style type="text/css">
.myTable { background-color:#E6F0FF;border: 1px solid blue;border-collapse: collapse; }
.myTable th { background-color:#0066FF;color:white;font-size: 100%; }
.myTable td { padding:3px;border:1px solid #0066FF; }

</style>
STYLE
    push(@HTML,"$STYLE");


    push(@HTML,"<table class=\"myTable\" border=1>\12<tr bgcolor=708090><th>EMPLOYEE_NAME</th><th>PHONE_NO</th></tr>");

    $retCode=executeSQL(" SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, PHONE_NO FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE");
 push(@HTML,"</table>\12\12");

 if($retCode) {
    push(@HTML,"<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><td></td>");
    push(@HTML,"<td></td><td></td></tr>\12");
    }


&sendMail;

sub sendMail
{

$sub="test report";
$from='abc@example.com';
$to='123@xample.com.com';

    open(MAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -t");
            print MAIL "From: $from \12"; print MAIL "To: $to \12";print MAIL "Cc: $Cc \12";
            print MAIL "Subject: $sub \12";
            print MAIL "Content-Type: text/html \12";
            print MAIL "Content-Disposition:inline \12";
            print MAIL @HTML;
 close(MAIL);
}
sub executeSQL
{
    my $SQL=$_[0];chomp($SQL);
    print "$SQL\12";



    my $dsn = "dbi:Oracle:host=server.com;sid=sample;port=1111;";
    my $dbuser = "username";
    my $dbpass = 'password';
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 });

    my $sth=$dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $sth->execute or die "EXEC ERROR $sth->errstr";
    $count=0;
    while (@ary = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
            $count++;
            push(@HTML,"<tr>");
            foreach(@ary) {
                    chomp($_);
                    push(@HTML,"<td>$_</td>");
                    print "$_,";
            }
            push(@HTML,"</tr>\12");
    }
    $dbh->disconnect();



print "COUNT : $count\12";
    return 1 if($count==0);

}
```

Comment: CSS cannot detect content. You need Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure whether I get it right when you want to "change background color during the load". But when the receiving e-mail-client renders your HTML, there is no dynamic process anymore - all database interaction is done by your script. Therefore, you can apply the background color in your perl script and you don't need JavaScript or even jQuery.

You have to change only small pieces of code:

In the "STYLE"-here-doc add

```
td.alert { padding:3px;border:1px solid #0066FF; background-color: #ff0000;}
```

modify the while-loop body of executeSQL like so:

```
$count++;
push(@HTML,"<tr>");
chomp($ary[0]);
push(@HTML,sprintf("<td%s>%s</td>",
                    ($ary[0] eq "steven") ? " class=\"alert\"" : "",
                    $ary[0]));

chomp($ary[1]);
push(@HTML,sprintf("<td%s>%s</td>",
                    (!length($ary[1]) || $ary[1] eq "1234") ? " class=\"alert\"" : "",
                    $ary[1]));

push(@HTML,"</tr>\12");
```

to highlight empty entries in the 2nd column or the entry "1234".

Comment: hi..i have modified the query but i get an syntax error while running.

Comment: i get an error while running the script..........syntax error at ./test.pl line 68, near ");"
syntax error at ./itest.pl line 73, near ");"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: sorry, these are the typos...: you have to add a closing parenthesis in those lines: `$ary[0]));` and `$ary[1]));`

Comment: you made my life very easy!!  that code works... two questions    1) now i am including two more columns in sql but i don't want add any bgcolour just printing.      2) for the single column i want to add  bgcolour have two conditions eg: phone_no = 1234 and phone_no=null (no value) i want highlight these cells in red.  Can you help to re-write the while loop code for the above two cases

Comment: It's been a long day for me, so I only did some minor changes. I suggest to do some more research on your own, since there are probably a lot of other changes you might need. Btw, when your life has been made easy, accepting the answer would be appreciated...

Comment: thanks i did bit research  and learned few things.. appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Leu, now i have created two mores styles Green and yellow. For the 2nd column how to conditionally change to Green or red depending on the values.  i have tries this but execution failed:                                          (!length($ary[2])|| $ary[2] eq "steve") ? " class=\"alert\"" || ( $ary[2] eq "paul") ? " class=\"alert1\"": "",

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way in CSS to do what you are expecting, in jQuery it's really simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(element).css('background-color','color');
});
```

Where `element` is the `#id` or `.class` or `div` you are using.

And `color` is the hex color you are planning to use like `#FF0000` which is red.

Instead of trying to do it difficultly just do it simple with jQuery.

Comment: hmm sorry,,, i am just new to jQuery i have attached my full code above for your reference.. can you edit it in jQuery satisfying my above two conditions

Comment: do you have any jQuery written?  I'm pretty new to html and don't know what everything in your code does. @stephenjacob